# How to set bootstrap input responsive width?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I need to do an inline form with calendar in both fields. for some reason i can't get rid of the extra space between the text and the borders of the input... here is a picture of the problem

[image]

I've tried to set width to the parent div and the input itself.... but no good..

Here is what I've done so far. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roybarak/duj0s5ev/6/):

```
      <div class="modify_search">
        <div class="search_wrapper">
          <div class="search_header">
            <form class="form-inline">
              <div class="left">
                <span>DU</span>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control search_input" id="inlineFormInputGroup">
                  <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="right">
                <span>DU</span>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control search_input" id="inlineFormInputGroup">
                  <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Here is the css :

```
      .search_input {
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        font-size: 24px;
        box-shadow: none;
      }

      .search_input:focus {
        box-shadow: none;
      }

      .modify_search {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: white;
        width: 60vw;
        height: 37vh;
        left: 50%;
        bottom: 5%;
        transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
        border-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 28px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 28px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 28px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
      }

      .left,
      .right {
        margin-right: 15px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
      }

      .left {
        float: left;
      }

      .right {
        float: right;
      }

      .search_header {
        padding: 15px 15px 0px 15px;
      }

      .input-group-addon {
        background-color: white;
        border: none;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're using bootstrap you have to apply the witdh to the `input-group` if you have another `input-group` with diferent width, just add a id to parent div and filter css class with that id

```
#less-width .input-group{
  width: 180px !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/duj0s5ev/8/

Or you can add it to a bootstrap column that fills the desired width

http://jsfiddle.net/duj0s5ev/11/

Comment: Thanks.... i'm not sure about this solution... it's messing up the divs...

Comment: @RoyBarOn 
Sorry dude, here i Tabulated better my second solution, were you can see how the input calendar takes width from bootstrap column jsfiddle.net/duj0s5ev/13

Comment: Arngue - thanks - but unfortunately nothing has changed - my goal was to remove the extra space to the left of the text and maintain the inputs inline.....